# How do I add parameter in django 2.0 using path

Tags: python, django

I've installed django version 2.0 and default for urls is path I know that if in django 1.x can be urls and follow with regular expression, how do I use path for parameters instead of urls, and so I dont want to use urls because django by default add path not urls if its can be or use urls still I want to know how to use a path with parameters in django 2.0

here's my code

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.articles_list),
    path('add', views.articles_add),
    path('edit', views.articles_edit)
]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
path('edit/<int:id>', views.articles_edit)
```

you can add parameters like this

in view

```
def articles_edit(request, id):
```

Comment: Can u please tell me how to reuse that parameter for other urls?

Answer (score 0):

Application `urls.py` File Add Following code

`path('blog/< int:blogid >', views.blog)`

Application `views.py` file, add following code:

`def blog(request, blogid):`

Make sure both place name should be same  (blogid)